# Change value of label in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I'm new in Xcode. I want to make a Progress View and below is a label. This label can change value from 1 to 100 just the same when the progress run. For example: when i tap the "Start" button then the progress run from 1 to 100, so does the label run from 1 to 100. Absolutely, i want to see to value change 1,2,3,4... of the label. Can anyone help me?

Code details attached is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://appsamuck.com/day1.html) logic to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks you, i just handle it.